# X509Certificate2.build() fails with partial chain ony on the first time

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate

In my program I am launching a different executable.
in order to verify that no one replaced that executable with something else, I check its signature.

Among other things, I am also verifying the certificate that was used to sign the certificate using [X509Chain.Build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain.build.aspx) (I am trying to build it on both machine and user store)

On one of my test machines I get a partial chain error when I try to build the chain. The issue cannot be reproduce after I close my application and then restart it.

I understand that I get this error because one of the certificates in the chain is missing, but I don't understand how on the next time I try to validate the certificate it's suddenly working.
I know that the store is updated automatically with all the required certificates after trying to check a specific certificate, so why the operation fails on the first time?
Any advice?

Comment: did you found what was causing this problem?

Comment: I am sorry, but no :(